# rename and run calculations based on column keywords

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a large dataframe where I want to rename and run different calculations based on column labels. My dataframe looks like this

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,8), columns = ('A_distance_km', 'A_costinUSD', 'B_distance_km' ,'B_costinUSD', 'C_distance_km', 'C_costinUSD', 'D_dosomething', 'D_dosomethingelse'))
```

I wrote this function to convert all distance columns to meters, and convert all costinUSD to costinEUR. But I ran into `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`. Any ideas how I should fix it?

```
def convert_units(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if col.str.contains("distance"):
            col = col + '_convert_m'
            df[col] = df[col]*1000
        elif col.str.contains("costinUSD"):
            df[col] = df[col]*0.95
        else:
            return col
    return df
```

Comment: `for col in df.columns` loops over the column names - in the `if` / `elif` you probably want `df[col].str.contains...` instead

Comment: `return col` is probably not expected/desirable in your case

Comment: @Mortz sadly I hit another error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` when using  `df[col].str.contains`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i tried removing `return col` too and still has the same attribute error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.columns` represents a sequence of strings (as column names), which implies basic `str` behavior.
To selectively rename and recalculate columns with a single traversal use the following approach:

```
def convert_units(df):
    rename_map = {}  # for columns to rename

    for col in df.columns:
        if "distance" in col:
            rename_map[col] = col + '_convert_m'
            df[col] *= 1000
        elif "costinUSD" in col:
            df[col] *= 0.95
    df = df.rename(columns=rename_map)

    return df

toy_df = convert_units(toy_df)
print(toy_df)
```

---

```
   A_distance_km_convert_m  A_costinUSD  B_distance_km_convert_m  B_costinUSD  C_distance_km_convert_m  C_costinUSD  D_dosomething  D_dosomethingelse
0                399.410277     0.127763               944.464091     0.599890               984.958983     0.431538       0.726368           0.603368
1                596.215569     0.834464                99.491461     0.161833               179.692729     0.327060       0.215208           0.288471
2                518.543479     0.451908               613.992588     0.112528               173.772711     0.554944       0.062708           0.019648
3                863.403168     0.469870               773.790350     0.686386               750.875558     0.241806       0.849428           0.988271
4                148.359791     0.832264               366.891421     0.077060               991.598502     0.884995       0.196801           0.302110
5                496.825790     0.509180               997.418855     0.455643               509.158725     0.666080       0.984209           0.915218
...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) holds labels/strings and not Series (that has a [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method).

I think you want to rename the columns (while preserving order?) and make the conditional computation. If so, following your approach, you can fix your code this way :

```
def convert_units(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        pos_col = df.columns.get_loc(col)
        if "distance" in col:
            df.insert(pos_col, col + "_convert_m", df.pop(col)*1000)
        elif "costinUSD" in col:
            df.insert(pos_col, col, df.pop(col)*0.95)

    return df
    
out = toy_df.pipe(convert_units) # or convert_units(toy_df)
```

Output :

```
print(out) # with `toy_df` seeded at 0

    A_distance_km_convert_m  A_costinUSD  ...  D_dosomething  D_dosomethingelse
0                    548.81         0.68  ...           0.44               0.89
1                    963.66         0.36  ...           0.07               0.09
2                     20.22         0.79  ...           0.46               0.78
3                    118.27         0.61  ...           0.26               0.77
4                    456.15         0.54  ...           0.94               0.68
..                      ...          ...  ...            ...                ...
45                   187.13         0.86  ...           0.72               0.40
46                   904.04         0.66  ...           0.24               0.16
47                   796.39         0.91  ...           0.95               0.58
48                   820.77         0.86  ...           0.06               0.42
49                   258.68         0.81  ...           0.02               0.19

[50 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest  @Timeless! A related question - multiplication works fine in these columns but will division work too?

Comment: Yes, you can slightly adjust *@RomanPerekhrest*'s code and use `df[col] /= 1000`.